# Spark read JDBC from SAS IOM

Tags: apache-spark, sas

I'm trying to read from SAS IOM using Spark JDBC. Problem is that the SAS JDBC driver is a bit strange, so i need to create my own dialect:

```
object SasDialect extends JdbcDialect {
  override def canHandle(url: String): Boolean = url.startsWith("jdbc:sasiom")
  override def quoteIdentifier(colName: String): String = "\"" + colName + "\"n"
}
```

however , this is not enough. SAS makes a distinction between column labels (= human readable names) and column names (= names you use in a SQL query), but it seems that spark uses the column labels instead of the names in schema discovery, see JdbcUtils extract below:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JdbcUtils.scala#L293

```
while (i < ncols) {
  val columnName = rsmd.getColumnLabel(i + 1)
```

this results in SQL errors because it tries to use the human readable column name in generated SQL code.

For SAS IOM JDBC to work, this would need to be the getColumnName instead of the getColumnLabel. Is there a way to specify this in the dialect ? I could not really find a way to hook into this, apart from wrapping the whole com.sas.rio.MVADriver and the resultsetmeta

Frank

Answer (score 1):

In the mean time i found how to do it, so just posting for reference. The trick is to register your own dialect, like below.

Also, SAS pads all varchar columns with spaces, so i trim all string columns.

```scala
  def getSasTable(sparkSession: org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession, tablename: String): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = {                                       
    val host : String = "dwhid94.msnet.railb.be";                                                                                                               
    val port : String = "48593";                                                                                                                                
    val props = new java.util.Properties();                                                                                                                     
    props.put("user", CredentialsStore.getUsername("sas"))                                                                                                      
    props.put("password", CredentialsStore.getPassword("sas"))                                                                                                  
    props.setProperty("driver", "com.sas.rio.MVADriver")                                                                                                        
    val sasconurl : String =  String.format("jdbc:sasiom://%s:%s", host, port);                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                
    object SasDialect extends JdbcDialect {                                                                                                                     
      override def canHandle(url: String): Boolean = url.startsWith("jdbc:sasiom")                                                                              
      override def quoteIdentifier(colName: String): String = "\"" + colName + "\"n"                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                                                           
    JdbcDialects.registerDialect(SasDialect)                                                                                                                    
    val df = sparkSession.read                                                                                                                                  
      .option("url", sasconurl)                                                                                                                                 
      .option("driver", "com.sas.rio.MVADriver")                                                                                                                
      .option("dbtable", tablename)                                                                                                                             
      .option("user",CredentialsStore.getUsername("sas"))                                                                                                       
      .option("password",CredentialsStore.getPassword("sas"))                                                                                                   
      .option("fetchsize",100)                                                                                                                                  
      .format("jdbc")                                                                                                                                           
      .load()                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                
    val strippedDf = sparkSession.createDataFrame(df.rdd.map(r => Row(r.toSeq.map(x => x match {case s: String => s.trim; case _ => x}): _*)), df.schema);      
    return strippedDf;                                                                                                                                          
  }
```

Comment: Note that SAS datasets do not have `varchar` variables. Only fixed length character strings and floating point numbers. Which is why you need to trim the values if you want to store as varchar without the trialing spaces.

Comment: I have the same problem. I want to load data from SAS via JDBC. Method `getColumnLabel` returns empty strings for all columns. Unfortunately, a custom dialect doesn't help in this case. Have you faced this kind of problem? I will be glad to hear any ideas about how to cope with this trouble